# How to add an alpha ordered list option in Redactor?

Tags: redactor

In addition to a bulleted unordered list and a numbered ordered list, I'd like to add an option to format text as an ordered list with upper-alpha letters, like this:

A.

B.

C.

D.

Can I add this to the list formatting menu somehow? If now, how would I create a custom formatting option that creates an `ol`?

**EDIT 9/4**

I am able to add custom formatting (with `formattingAdd`) to create `<ol class="my-class"></ol>`, but I haven't found a way to allow `li` elements to be created inside it.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up making a custom redactor plugin for this. Code at https://github.com/FosterCommerce/redactor-alphalist (repo is currently private but should be published soon).

Comment: Great :) Yes, didn't think about adding in the li's! Plugin seemed the only way.

Comment: Brilliant! Looks like the repo is public, now—will use this for reference if we find ourselves in a similar situation!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can add a [custom redactor config](https://github.com/craftcms/redactor#configuration) and add in the [formattingAdd setting](https://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/settings/formatting/#s-formattingadd). Eg.

```
formattingAdd: {
    "alpha-ordered": {
        title: 'Alpha Ordered',
        api: 'module.block.format',
        args: {
            'tag': 'ol',
            'class': 'alpha-ordered'
        }
    },
}
```

You can then style this with css:

```
.alpha-ordered {
    list-style-type:upper-alpha
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is it only creates `ol`s, not `li`s, and it will keep creating new `ol` elements every time you click it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you're looking for is a combination of two customizations:

1. Adding a custom formatting button via Redactor's [`formattingAdd` option](https://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/settings/formatting/#s-formattingadd). Config example below!
2. Custom CP CSS rules to style the list in the Redactor field as your editor expects it. The strategy for this is up to you, but Double Secret Agency has the simplest method via their [Control Panel CSS plugin](https://plugins.craftcms.com/cp-css).
3. Of course, front-end styles to match.

Redactor will expect something like this for your custom formatting rule:

```
{
    "buttons": ["italic", "bold"],
    "formattingAdd": {
        "ol-alpha": {
            "title": "Create Letter",
            "api": "module.block.format",
            "args": {
                "tag": "ol",
                "attr": {
                    "class": "my-alpha-ordered-list-class"
                },
                "type": "toggle"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(This was adapted from Craft's built-in `Simple.json` config!)

> Keep in mind! This will add a new option to the "Formatting" drop-down menu (i.e. where the headings, `blockquote`, etc. might appear), *not* with the List options. I'm not sure exactly how to adjust the options in that menu…

The answer from @user3788089 is about 99% there—I think the only new thing above is re: styling *within* the control panel. ✌️

Comment: Thanks! That's one thing I tried, and it does show up in the formatting menu and create `<ol class="list-alpha">My Text<ol>`, but I can't figure out how to add `li` elements inside it. Any ideas?

Comment: Shooooot! Interesting! I hadn't considered that the list functionality was different, in this respect. It might be possible to make your `fomattingAdd` option just toggle a class on the existing `ol` and/or `li` elements, rather than convert it to/from an `ol`? (Effectively, I think this would mean just removing the `tag` key from the config, above)

Comment: No, but I found an answer! See below (sorry code is private at the moment, waiting to make sure it's okay to create a public repo in my company's account).